# I want to create a new column territory based on the city column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Data Frame :

```
      city  Temperature
0   Chandigarh  15
1   Delhi       22
2   Kanpur      20
3   Chennai     26
4   Manali      -2
0   Bengalaru   24
1   Coimbatore  35
2   Srirangam   36
3   Pondicherry 39
```

I need to create another column in data frame, which contains a boolean value for each city to indicate whether it's a union territory or not. Chandigarh, Pondicherry and Delhi are only 3 union territories here.

I have written below code

```
import numpy as np
conditions = [df3['city'] == 'Chandigarh',df3['city'] == 'Pondicherry',df3['city'] == 'Delhi']
values =[1,1,1]
df3['territory'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

Is there any easier or efficient way that I can write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
union_terrs = ["Chandigarh", "Pondicherry", "Delhi"]
df3["territory"] = df3["city"].isin(union_terrs).astype(int)
```

which checks each entry in `city` column and if it is in `union_terrs`, gives `True` and otherwise `False`. The `astype` makes `True/False` to `1/0` conversion,

to get

```
          city  Temperature  territory
0   Chandigarh           15          1
1        Delhi           22          1
2       Kanpur           20          0
3      Chennai           26          0
4       Manali           -2          0
0    Bengalaru           24          0
1   Coimbatore           35          0
2    Srirangam           36          0
3  Pondicherry           39          1
```